# JQuery - My tags box doesn't work because i'm using the clone() event

Tags: jquery

i created a little script, when i write on my textbox and i click space, the words that i written, goes to a hidden area, and separated, they appear like tags.

Google use this script for Gmail, when you write your contacts, and for Youtube too, when you write your video tags.

So, o created this script, and its working really well.

But now i want to create a new script, that clones my form, every moment that i click at a link, a new form equal to the last, appears.

I used "Clone()" to do that, its working, but i cant call my hidden form tags, resuming, "clone()" cant read my tags.

I'm new at jQuery, so, i want to know how can i make the event clone() read my tags.

Here my jQuery code for the tags:

```
   $('#tags').keypress(function(e) { //Check if space was clicked, and create a new tag
       if(e.which == 32) {
           var tx = $('#tags').val();
           if (tx) {
            $(this).val('').parent().before('<li class="tags"><span><input type="hidden" value="'+tx+'" name="tags[]" />'+tx+'</span><a style="cursor:pointer;" id="close">[x]</a></li>');
               closer();
           }
       }
   });
```

And my HTML input box

```
  <label>Tags<a class="required_field">*</a></label>
      <div id="wrapbox">
         <div id="box">
            <span id="checktags"></span>
            <input type="text" class="to-be-clicked" id="tags" class="tagstype" maxlength="230">
         </div>
      </div>
```

And i'm using this code to clone the form

```
     $(".add").click(function(){
    $("#job").clone().appendTo("body");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default **clone()** method its pass false argument in **clone(false)**,

You can pass **Boolean** value with clone parameter, boolean indicating whether event handlers should be **copied** along with the **elements**.

```
$("#job").clone(true).appendTo("body");
```

**[*Clone()*](http://api.jquery.com/clone/)** Method Documentation

Hope this would be help you!

Comment: Still not working, because my hidden input is outside the form, thats why he can't read.

Comment: yes not read. but you try parent() or next() jquery method may be help you.